# How to conect 2D array in port map in vhdl v93 or v2002

Tags: arrays, vhdl, hdl

This is my component, type and signal:

```
    type t_data_bus_array is array(natural range<>, natural range<>) of std_logic;

        component credit
              generic (
                 CREDIT_WIDTH      : natural := 4   
              );
              port (

                 pi     : in  std_logic_vector(CREDIT_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
                 po     : out std_logic_vector(CREDIT_WIDTH-1 downto 0)
              );
        end component;

signal pi_credit_array         : t_data_bus_array(NUMBER_OF_INPUTS-1 downto 0, CREDIT_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
signal po_credit_array         : t_data_bus_array(NUMBER_OF_INPUTS-1 downto 0, CREDIT_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
```

In my architekture, I would try to connect them, but this do not work.

```
Credit_X : for I in 0 to NUMBER_OF_INPUTS-1 generate
   Credit_I :
      credit
      generic map(
         CREDIT_WIDTH      => CREDIT_WIDTH   
      )
         pi  => pi_credit_array(I),        
         po  => po_credit_array(I)    
      );
   end generate;
```

Also try with function:

```
   -- select specifik row in 2d array 
   function sel_chunk(
      data  : t_data_bus_array;  -- matrix of std_logic
      num   : natural;           -- selected row
      width : natural            -- width of row 
   ) return std_logic_vector is
      variable data_ret_val : std_logic_vector(width-1 downto 0);
   begin
      for i in data_ret_val'range loop
         data_ret_val(i) := data (num, i);
      end loop;
      return data_ret_val;
   end sel_chunk;
```

And use function like this:

```
Credit_calculator_X : for I in 0 to NUMBER_OF_INPUTS-1 generate
   Credit_calculator_I :
      credit_calculator
      generic map(
         CREDIT_WIDTH      => CREDIT_WIDTH  
      )
         pi  => sel_chunk( pi_credit_array, I, CREDIT_WIDTH ),      
         po => sel_chunk( po_credit_array, I, CREDIT_WIDTH )   
      );
   end generate;
```

**So, How to fix this problem and connect 2D array in port map?**

Comment: Provide a [mcve] so you don't end up with wavy handed answers. [Your problem as presented requires neither a 2D array type nor a function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9pol.jpg). Here that means showing why you need a multi-dimensional interface object connected to credit.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `t_data_bus_array` is a 2D array type. `std_logic_vector` is a 1d array type. In VHDL, multi-dimensional array types cannot be sliced at all, so you need to create a function to convert your custom 2D array type into a std_logic_vector.    In VHDL '93 you cannot use a function in a port map, so you would need a temprary signal to do the conversion function on the port map :

```
signal tmp : std_logic_vector(CREDIT_WIDTH-1 downto 0);

tmp <= sel_chunk(pi_credit_array, I, CREDIT_WIDTH);

....
port map (
  pi => tmp,
```

or alternatively, just use VHDL 2008, where functions are allowed on port maps.

Alternatively, it may just be simpler to create a 1D array of std_logic_vector, because that can be sliced. In VHDL 2008, array types can be declared with the element type also unconstrained, so that the dimensions can all be constrained when a object is declared.

eg.

```
type t_data_bus_array is array(natural range <>) of std_logic_vector;

signal pi_credit_array   : t_data_bus_array(NUMBER_OF_INPUTS-1 downto 0)(CREDIT_WIDTH-1 downto 0);

....

port map (
  pi => pi_credit_array(I),
```

Generally, creating a 2d array type of std_logic is going to make your life difficult. Avoid if possible.

Comment: I am using  XCELIUM 18.03-s001 how to turn on VHDL2008. Have only -v200x and -v93 but not VHDL 2008.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I fix problem with input signal in port map with idea pi => tmp, what to do with output signal. Where to define temp signal and how?

Comment: You'll need another temporary signal of `std_logic_vector`. Then you'll need another function to apply a std_logic_vector to your output 2d array.